# Adjusting the size in a simple form

Tags: sapui5

I am developing an application using SAPUI5 and I am having a problem with the sizing of the "dropdownbox" in a simple form. The items from sap.m package seem to automatically adjust to the size of the simple form content, while other items from packages like sa.ui.commons don't adjust as well.

How do I adjust the size of the dropdownbox? I tried setting the width and the height to "100%" but that did not work.

Adding the code:

```xml
<c:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:c="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:co="sap.ui.commons"
    xmlns:col="sap.ui.commons.layout"
    xmlns="sap.m">
        <l:Grid
        defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
        width="auto">
        <l:content>
            <f:SimpleForm
            
                minWidth="800"
                maxContainerCols="2"
                editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                title="General Info"
                labelSpanL="3"
                labelSpanM="3"
                emptySpanL="4"
                emptySpanM="4"
                columnsL="2"
                columnsM="2"
                class="editableForm">
                <f:content>
                    <Label text="Employee Name" />
                    <co:DropdownBox   width="200px" >
                        <c:ListItem text="Emp1"/>
                        <c:ListItem text="Emp2"/>
                    </co:DropdownBox> 
                    <Label text="Type of Travel" />
                    <Select >
                        <c:ListItem key="B" text="Business"/>
                        <c:ListItem key="O" text="Other"/>
                    </Select>
                   
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
</c:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: Voting to close this question as `sap.ui.commons` is deprecated and incompatible with `sap.m` to which the author agreed. This question is less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

How about just omitting the width of the `commons` control, just as you did with the `m` control? That scales the `sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox` just as wide as the `sap.m.Select` control.

On a sidenote, I would not mix `m` controls with `common` controls; you may run into CSS issues

---

EDIT: See this working example, both `sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox` and `sap.m.Select` are of equal size:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
  onInit : function() { }
});

var app = new sap.m.App({});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
});

app.addPage(oView);
app.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>SAPUI5 template</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

    <script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
        <mvc:View 
          controllerName="view1.initial"
          xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
          xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
          xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
          xmlns:c="sap.ui.core"
          xmlns:co="sap.ui.commons"
          xmlns:col="sap.ui.commons.layout"
          xmlns="sap.m">
            <l:Grid
            defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
            width="auto">
                <l:content>
                    <f:SimpleForm

                        minWidth="800"
                        maxContainerCols="2"
                        editable="true"
                        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                        title="General Info"
                        labelSpanL="3"
                        labelSpanM="3"
                        emptySpanL="4"
                        emptySpanM="4"
                        columnsL="2"
                        columnsM="2"
                        class="editableForm">
                        <f:content>
                            <Label text="Employee Name" />
                            <co:DropdownBox>
                                <c:ListItem text="Emp1"/>
                                <c:ListItem text="Emp2"/>
                            </co:DropdownBox> 
                            <Label text="Type of Travel" />
                            <Select>
                                <c:ListItem key="B" text="Business"/>
                                <c:ListItem key="O" text="Other"/>
                            </Select>

                        </f:content>
                    </f:SimpleForm>
                </l:content>
            </l:Grid>
        </mvc:View>
    </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="uiArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wont work, the size becomes even smaller. It would not scale it as big as the control. That's the problem I am facing.

Comment: Not sure what goes wrong, see my updated answer using your code

Comment: The height is still different, and when I use it within my application its not the same width :(

Comment: Well yeah, of course the height is different, it is a totally different control, what did you expect then :-) You may change the CSS to alter the height. However, the width should adapt just fine, you must have made a coding/css-width error somewhere. But again, I would not mix commons and m controls.

Comment: yeah, you are absolutely right. I shouldnt mix those libraries. I will stick to one and see how ti looks. Thanks!

Comment: @ducks13 As [stated in the documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820), those two libs shouldn't be used together. Since it's already what Qualiture suggested, I'd recommend to accept his answer, also to inform others that the issue is resolved by this.